# importing 'external' package in anacona python - unexpected behaviour

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda

I am using anaconda Python (on a Linux) and try to import a additional package ("vespa") installed in

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/vespa
```

threfore outside the anaconda installation via

```
import sys
sys.append('/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/vespa')
```

The vespa folder contains an empty __init__.py and many subfolder (modules).
However, I always get an import error, whether I try to import vespa itself or an specific submodule:

```
import vespa
ImportError: No module named vespa
```

However, another package "pygamma" works fine and I can import it inside anaconda python via

```
sys.append('/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pygamma')
import pygamma
```

The only difference is, that the pygamma folder contains an pygamma.py, whereas the vespa folder contains only submodules.
I also gave "vespa" full permission via chmod -R 777. All "vespa" modules contain their own __init__.py.

I assume I missing something very basic in the import mechanism in Python, would appreciate a hint, since working from anaconda python is quite convenient.

Cheers,
Michael

Comment: `sys.append('/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages')` and then `import vespa`. You want to import package (effectively - a directory), not file within it.

Comment: thanks, that solves the problem...